# How can I force the textbox of ComboBox only can input double?

Tags: wpf

I wanna use a ComboBox to store&input the font size.

So I created a `ComboBox` and set the `IsEditable` to true.

And now the problem comes, I don't know how to force the textbox of ComboBox only can input `double`?

How can I do this? Would you please help me?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could handle the `PreviewTextInput` and `DataObject.Pasting` events. Something like this:

```
private void ComboBox_PreviewTextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = !IsValid(e.Text);
}

private void ComboBox_Pasting(object sender, DataObjectPastingEventArgs e)
{
    if (!e.DataObject.GetDataPresent(typeof(string)) || !IsValid(e.DataObject.GetData(typeof(string)) as string))
        e.CancelCommand();
}

private static bool IsValid(string s)
{
    double d;
    return double.TryParse(s, NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out d);
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<ComboBox IsEditable="True" PreviewTextInput="ComboBox_PreviewTextInput"
              DataObject.Pasting="ComboBox_Pasting" ... >
```

Answer (score 1):

You can handle it in the ComboBox's PreviewTextInput event as same as a TextBox.

Xaml:

```
<ComboBox IsEditable="True" PreviewTextInput="ComboBox_PreviewTextInput"/>
```

Code:

```
private void ComboBox_PreviewTextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
{
    var approvedDecimalPoint = false;
    if (e.Text == ".")
    {
        if (!((ComboBox)sender).Text.Contains("."))
            approvedDecimalPoint = true;
    }
    if (!(char.IsDigit(e.Text, e.Text.Length - 1) || approvedDecimalPoint))
        e.Handled = true;
}
```

Or you can use `Regex` too.

Comment: I tried this way but it can't prevent someone from pastes data to it. What's more, if I use an input method(such as the Microsoft Pinyin input method) input something which is not English, it still can input successfully.